# If I set a system property with -D can I access it from my code?

Tags: java, properties, jvm

I'd like to be able to set a property on the JVM using the `-D` switch. If I do that, can I access it from my code? If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`System.getProperty("mykey");`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String))

Comment: Try it out and check the link

Comment: @Geo, yes `mykey` can be any string.  However, there are a number of properties already defined by default.  There's a list of them in the Java documentation at this page. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 3):

Apart from `System.getProperty`, there's also `Integer.getInteger` and `Boolean.getBoolean`, if you want to get an integral or boolean value instead. :-)

Answer (score 1):

and as a bonus:

```
System.setProperty("yourkey",yourValue); //works very well too
```

allows you to make sure the property is set if you want to test things